# Valid characters for a REST identifier

Tags: rest

The product group in the company I work for is asking that we use an ID for a REST identifier that would require URL encoding (any character is allowed), and is also mutable. One last thing is that the field they want to use is only unique because of unique index on the table's column.

I think this is a terrible idea. Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if your "question" is actually on topic for SO. A mutable ID for things (resource, db entries, ...) in general isn't ideal as due to the mutable nature it might change at some point preventing the lookup of it in future. In regards to REST, Fielding mentioned [this](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and [that](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm#sec_6_2) in regards to resource identifiers

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I appreciate. I was not sure about posting here, but after searching around I couldn't find the words I was looking for. I have come to trust the community at SO. I can delete this question if it becomes an issue.